# How to calculate the mean/sd of a vector without using the in-built R function?

Tags: r, function, standards, mean

this must be a very simple fix but I'm just struggling to figure out. I'm trying to write a function that will take a vector of numbers and calculate its mean and another function to calculate the sd. This is what I have now:

```
calc_avg <- function(vec){
  print(sum(vec)/length(vec))
}

list_d <- list(5,5)
calc_avg(list_d)
```

The error that's shown is this: `Error in sum(vec) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument`

In my head the function is very simple, but for whatever reason the `sum` function of R doesn't recognize the `vec` variable. If I just define it normally, it works fine.

Any help would be much appreciated, and yes, I'm 100% a noob when it comes to R.

Thanks.

Comment: If you run a function in R at the console it will print the return value automatically so you likely don't need the print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a `list`, and `sum` requires a `vector`.  According to `?sum`

> ... - numeric or complex or logical vectors.

So, `unlist` the `list` to convert it to `vector`

```
calc_avg(unlist(list_d))
#[1] 5
```